# Angularjs reset state of factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I have a service that makes a GET request and passes a start param. The start param is incremented within the factory
    this.start++

When i click on a link the service needs to make a request but the start parameter doesn't get reset it just keeps incrementing. I don't want to introduce a reset function the sets it to 0 prior a call because that gets messy when i ll have to keep track of multie attributes.

I understand why this happens, since there is only 1 instance of the factory within my app. 
But i don't know what the angular way is to reset a factory to its original state.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

```
myApp.factory('myFactory', function ($http) {
   return{
     start: 0,
     get: function() {
        var that = this;
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'some-url',
            params: that.getParams(),
        }).success(function(data){
                that.start++;
        });
    },
});


 myApp.factory('myFactory1', function (myFactory) {
    myFactory.getParams = function() {
     return {
       limit:10,
       custom: true,
       name: 'some-name',
       start: myFactory.start

     };
   }
   return myFactory;
});

myApp.factory('myFactory2', function (myFactory) {
    myFactory.getParams = function() {
     return {
       limit:5,
       custom: false,
       surname: 'some-surname' 
       start: myFactory.start
     };
   }
   return myFactory;
});
```

So in this case I when i click on different links (or browser back/forward) either myFactory1 or myFactory2 are called , GET data based on different params. The problem is that since services are singletons the start param keeps updating. I can have a reset function to reset through either myFacroty1 or 2 but it doesn't seem right

Comment: that sounds like bad design. the whole purpose of a service is being a singleton which gets instantiated only once. if you need that functionality, you should add a reset method or use something else than a service

Comment: The purpose of that is so i can reuse the service to get data and only provide different GET params each time. If i treat it as a singleton then my alternative is code dublication

Comment: i think you need to provide a more detailed description of your task, maybe i can help with it when i understand what you exactly want to achieve